# How to redirect signup page after successfull registration in wordpress without plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

1.This is my signup page. This page redirect to http://mysite.com/wp-login.php?checkemail=registered.. i want to go to custom page.. please help me

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Sign-up
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="site-content">
        <div id="content" role="main">
  <h2><strong>Sign up</strong></h2>

          <form action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=register', 'login') ?>" class="user_new" id="user_new" method="post">
                <p> <input id="user_login" name="user_login" size="30" type="text" placeholder="Select a username"></p>

<p>                 <input id="user_email" name="user_email" size="30" type="text" placeholder="Email address"></p>

                 <?php do_action('register_form'); ?>

                <input id="register" type="submit" value="Sign up">
          </form>
          <p>A password will be emailed to you</p>
          <p>Already a user? <a href="/login/" >Login</a>!</p>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following plugin will help you solve this problem.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/rename-wp-login/

In the Settings permalink you can manage the URL for login page and this will act as redirect rule for all wp admin pages.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but i want some code.. without plugin